# Unable to import keras-gpu in spyder

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, spyder

I was trying to use keras-gpu with tensorfow-gpu.
However I am unable to  import keras in spyder environment:

```
import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-1-c74e2bd4ca71>", line 1, in <module>
import keras

File "C:\Users\Souvik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import utils

File "C:\Users\Souvik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import conv_utils

File "C:\Users\Souvik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
from .. import backend as K

File "C:\Users\Souvik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
from .tensorflow_backend import *

File "C:\Users\Souvik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 6, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.training import moving_averages

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 890, in _find_spec

File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 864, in _find_spec_legacy

File "C:\Users\Souvik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 253, in find_module
fp, pathname, (ext,mode,ty) = imp.find_module(fullname,package_path)

File "C:\Users\Souvik\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 271, in find_module
"not {}".format(type(path)))

RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>
```

I am unable to find any related errors on the web. Please help to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This error was fixed in Spyder **3.2.8**, released in March of 2018. So please update Spyder to that version to get the fix.